# How to prevent a re-render with a functional component and react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

**Issue**: Web Application re-rendering with input onChange event, thus causing socket to disconnect then reconnect.

**Detail**:
I am creating a small multiplayer game with Socket.io, React, Express, PostgreSql, and Nodejs.
I would like the user to be able to search for a room name with an input box and a submit button or create a game with a button.

**Question**: Is there a way to prevent a re-render when the user inputs the room code in the input box?

---

**Code**:

*App.js*

```js
const App = () => {
    const socket = io();
    const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState('');

        // CREATE ROOM CODE
    const createRoom = () => {
        socket.emit('create', true)
        socket.once('roomCreated', room => {
            axios.post(`/room/roomCode?room=${room}`)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(err => console.warn(err))
        })
    }

        // JOIN SPECIFIC ROOM
    const joinRoom = () => {
        axios.post(`/room/findRoom?roomCode=${roomCode}`)
            .then(({ response }) => {
                console.info(response)
            })
            .catch(err => console.warn(err))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button
                onClick={createRoom}
            >
                Create
            </button>
            <input
                placeholder="Room Code"
                onChange={(e) => { setRoomCode(e.target.value) }}
            />
            <button onClick={joinRoom}>
                Enter Room Code
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

*Room.js route*

```js
roomRouter.post('/findRoom', (req, res) => {
    const { roomCode } = req.query
    Room.findOne({
        where: {
            room_code: roomCode,
        }
    })
        .then(room => {
            room ? res.send(room) : res.send('room does not exist')
        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
})
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing your socket declaration to

```
 const [socket] = useState(io());
```

should fix the issue.

Or simple move it outside the component

Comment: If you keep it inside the component, `useRef` is a much better option.

Answer (score 1):

Each time state changes, the entire component is re-rendered, including your first line `const socket = io()`. Try moving that line on top of your component like so:

```
const socket = io()

const App = () => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: AMAZING. That solved my issue. Something so easy.

Comment: If this resolved your issue please mark it as the correct answer :)